# Fading in and out with a delay in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I wondered if anyone can help me with this, I've searched google but I don't see a question where they want to fade in AND out, only one of them.

I want to fade a div in slowly, wait 5 seconds, then fade it out slowly. Can this be done?

I haven't really tried anything because I don't know where to start.

Comment: perhaps using CSS animation/transition as a starting point

Comment: Maybe if you learn how to fade in, and then learn how to fade out, you could somehow combine that knowledge to fade both in and out.

Comment: I wouldn't know how, because it conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with basic JavaScript and jQuery. `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` both method are in jQuery, so you should also tag jQuery in your question. Here I gave you an example how to do that.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeOut(2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
 $('#div1').fadeIn(2000);
    }, 5000);
})
```

```css
#div1{
    width:90%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    this is the div
</div>
```